# Mixed xml / text parsing python

Tags: python, xml, regex

I need to parse some Log-files in this ugly format
(Any number of plaintext headers where some of those headers got additional data in xml):

```
[dd/mm/yy]:message_data
<starttag>
    <some_field>some_value</some_field>
     ....
</starttag>
[dd/mm/yy]:message_data
[dd/mm/yy]:message_data
....
```

So far my approach is:

```
    message_text = None
    for line in LOGFILE:

        message_start_match = MESSAGE_START_RE.search(line)
        if not message_start_match:
            header_info = HEADER_RE.search(line)

        if message_start_match:
            message_text = line
            continue
        if message_text:
            message_text += line

        if MESSAGE_END_RE.search(line):
            process_message_with_xml_parser(message_text, header_info)
            message_text=None
```

where

```
MESSAGE_START_RE = re.compile(r"<starttag.*>)
MESSAGE_END_RE = re.compile(r"</starttag>)
header_info is a regex with named fields of the message
```

**Do you know any better way?**

The Problem in this aproach is: I am sort of parsing xml with regex (which is stupid). Is there any package which can recognize start and end of xml in file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `BeautifulSoup` on your ugly xml. Here is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """[dd/mm/yy]:message_data
<starttag>
    <some_field>some_value</some_field>
     ....
</starttag>
[dd/mm/yy]:message_data
[dd/mm/yy]:message_data"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data);
starttag = soup.findAll("starttag")
for tag in starttag:
    print tag.find("some_field").text
    # => some_value
```

Comment: Thanks, this is already thought about this approach. But I could not find any way to combine the line `[dd/mm/yy]:message_data]` (which contains the message meta information, like timestamp, issuer) with `tag.find("some_field").text` Beautifulsoup does not provide the line number of the match

Comment: Those are outside tags. You can use `soup.text` and then parse text from there as there will not be any `xml` tag on it.